# How to check if model has something inside in django?

Tags: python, django, web

I have a model of `Branch`, and a model of `Worker`. I want to filter only these branches, which have at least one user inside.

`models.py`

```
class Branch(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Worker(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='branch')
    position = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I tried to add `related_name` to `worker`-`branch`, but now I don't know how to use it, and is it right way to do so?
I also tried to filter like that: `Worker.objects.filter(branch=?).exists()`. But it doesn't make sense.

At the end I want to have a list of branches which have at least one worker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and let me know if it helps, it should work, not sure though:

```
Branch.objects.filter(branch__isnull=False)
```

Not elegant at all, but you could also use Count and queryset annotation. Also, "branch" is a terrible name for a set of users assigned to a branch, so the related name should be "users" or "assigned_users" or so.

EDIT:

```
Branch.objects.filter(branch__isnull=False).distinct()
```

to get rid of duplicates

Comment: 1. It kinda works, but I can't get the point. I tried your example and now I have list. If I print it, it looks like that: `<QuerySet [<Branch: Branch 1>, <Branch: Branch 1>, <Branch: Branch 1>, <Branch: Branch 2>]>`. I have 4 workers right now. But it's not what I want.   2. How should I give related names? What are the rules?

Comment: Well, you get a set of Branches, because you perform a query on Branch object. You get a list of branches that have at least one user assigned: "Give me all branches having more than 0 users"

Comment: Related names go like so:
Let's say customers have orders. In this case, on the Order model:
customer = ForeignKey(Customer, related_name="orders")
That's because order has a customer, but customer has orders.

Comment: You can also append distinct() at the end, to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the following approach (easier to read):

```
Branch.objects.exclude(branch__isnull=True)
```